# Select two null columns in a row and insert value in any one of these columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sid = xxxx.

And a table with tablename 'room' and columnnames sid1,sid2 and sid3 .
How i can check which column is null and insert sid value in any one of these null columns.

```
sid1    sid2    sid3    roomno
NULL    2222    NULL    1
5432    NULL    NULL    2
```

Comment: your table structure is wrong

Comment: Can a room have more than one `sidX` value? If so I think you would want to have a table with the definition `roomno, sid` and then have multiple rows per room

Comment: That was very quick edit . Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just 3 columns, this isn't too bad . . .

```
update room
    set sid1 = (case when sid1 is null then $newval else sid1 end),
        sid2 = (case when sid1 is not null and sid2 is null then $newval else sid2 end),
        sid3 = (case when sid1 is not null and sid2 is not null and sid3 is null then $newval else sid3 end)
    where roomno = $roomno;
```

However, I strongly recommend that you create a junction table, with one row per sid and one per room.

Comment: It worked , there is slight mistake in your above code , you have two times same sid2 =

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're setting `sid2` twice, the second one should be `sid3`